# How to write if else in short

Tags: php

Someone show me how I can write this line of codes in short.

```
if($x[$key_url] == $last_news)          
{
    $new_next = $first; 
}
else{
    $new_next = $x[$key_url + 2];   
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: Duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

Using [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) it becomes:

```
$new_next = $x[$key_url] == $last_news ? $first : $x[$key_url + 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example

```
$new_next = $x[$key_url + 2];   
if($x[$key_url] == $last_news) {
   $new_next = $first; 
}
```

Or

```
 $new_next =  ($x[$key_url] == $last_news) ? $first : $x[$key_url + 2];
```

Comment: It works bro Thanks!

Comment: @Didos Rukundo Thanks a lot, I have upvoted your question can you please upvote my answer and accept it for my stackoverflow career 
thanks a lot